# C programming: how to fopen a designated file and dynamically allocate its contents into a 2D array?

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, fopen, scanf

Basically my program prompts the user to enter the name of a file that he wants to open. My program is supposed to open that file and scan its contents into a 2D array. But how do you do it so that the program opens the file that the user designates? Here's my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
FILE *open_file(int ar[3][4]);

int main()
{
  FILE *fp;
  int ar[3][4];

  fp = open_file(ar);
}

FILE *open_file(int ar[3][4])
{
  FILE *fp;
  int i;
  char file[80];
  printf("Please input file name ");
  scanf("%s", &file); //am I supposed to have written ("%s", file) instead?
  fp = fopen("%s", "r");// very confused about this line; will this open the file?
  for (i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &ar[i][]); //how do you scan the file into a 2D array?
}
```

To use malloc, I'd have to write something like fp = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));?

Answer (score 1):

```
scanf("%s", &file); // am I supposed to have written ("%s", file) instead?
```

Yes, but not for the reason you would think. So

```
scanf("%s", file);
```

is correct instead (explanation: the `%s` format specifier tells `scanf()` to expect a `char *`, but you're passing it a `char (*)[80]` if you write the addressof operator, and mismatching type specifiers for `printf()` and `scanf()` invoke undefined behavior).

```
fp = fopen("%s", "r"); // very confused about this line; will this open the file?
```

No, it won't. It will open the file named `%s`. You have to write

```
fp = fopen(file, "r");
```

instead. Don't assume you can use a format string where you can't.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you. Could you help me with dynamically allocating the file contents into an array using malloc?

Comment: +1: very interesting. Could you explain a litter more? the malloc and the use... In the body of the answer, please

Comment: @qPCR4vir Specifically? (Sorry, but I'm not giving full lectures in SO comments. You should search for a complete and exhaustive C tutorial and learn the language.)

Comment: OK. But this is not a trivial use of malloc.

Comment: @qPCR4vir What do you mean by that? What's not trivial? (Or similarly, what would be a trivial use of `malloc()` that even a 3-year-old could do without even knowing C?)

Answer (score 0):

The varialble `file` contains the name of the file entered by the user, so pass it to fopen. What you have there is a format string.

```
fp = fopen(file, "r");
```